# How to solve vector-valued first order linear pde?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Is there an analytical solution to the pde system?

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = 0$$

More generally, how about
$$a\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + b\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = 0$$
$$c\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} - d\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = 0$$
where $a,b,c,d$ are all constants.

Maybe now analytical solution depends on these coefficients and thus be hard or unclear, in which case a proof of existence is wanted. (**Does here Frobenius theorem help?**)

Answer (score 2):

These are the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) in disguise. They say that $f-ig$ is a holomorphic function of $z=x+iy$.

Comment: Yes, it is. Actually, I wanna know about if Frobenius theorem helps here?

Answer (score 1):

I assume $f, g$ are scalar fields.  Let $A(x,y) = f(x,y) \hat x + g(x,y) \hat y$.  This system is equivalent to

$$\nabla \cdot A = 0, \quad \nabla \times A = 0$$

The vector field $A$ is entirely determined by boundary values.  You can attack such a problem using the generalized Stokes theorem, but the expressions are a bit involved.

However, since this is a 2d problem, you can instead use complex analysis and the Cauchy integral formula.  The condition $\nabla \cdot A = 0, \nabla \times A = 0$ for a vector field is *entirely equivalent* to saying there is a corresponding complex function $a$ that is holomorphic.

Thus, at some complex point $z$, you can find the value of $a$ by

$$a(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{a(z')}{z - z'} \, dz'$$

For some suitably chosen closed path with nice, known values on the boundary, this could have an analytic solution.

Comment: Hah, you mean, geometric algebra? In view of that, could the uniqueness of solution to pde be guaranteed? I mean, $\nabla\cdot A$ gives a scalar, which provides one constraint, while $\nabla\times A$ is a bivector imposing $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ constraint(s). What's the relationship between $\frac{n(n-1)}{2} + 1$ constraints and $n$ dimension?

Comment: That's a thought-provoking question.  Naively, one wouldn't think more than $n$ equations should be all that is necessary to determine the $n$ components of a vector field.  But, those are the equations generated using the fundamental theorem.  Very interesting thought that I will have to ruminate over.

Comment: Yes, my point is that it may be of great importance to determine number of constraints that $\nabla\times A$ imposes. It seems that that many equations are dependent. Anyway, please inform me whenever you get any idea. I would be of great appreciation.

Comment: Ah, of course, one expects that the components are only fully described when all $n$ partial derivatives are known.  So naively, there should be $n^2$ derivatives specified, but combining the diagonal terms into a trace (the scalar, divergence) is instead enough.  So the question is why we can use less information to fully characterize the vector field.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused with $n$ and $n^2$. Say, if we have an $n$ dimensional vector $u$ satisfying $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ equations $\nabla\times u=0$, then $u$ can be completely solved implied by Poincare lemma. That is $u=d\varphi$ for any smooth function $\varphi$. No more equation required. Did you mean $\nabla\times u=0$ is surely an under-determined pde system?

Comment: I wasn't speaking of curl there, just that there are $n$ component functions and each of those components has $n$ partial derivatives with respect to the coordinates.  $n \times n = n^2$, after all.  But there must be some redundant information here; perhaps through the equality of mixed partial derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an analytical solution for the first system

> $$  f \left( x,y \right)={ F_1} \left( y-ix \right) +{ 
> F_2} \left( y+ix \right),$$
>
> $$ \,g \left( x,y \right) = i{ F_1} \left( y-i x\right)-i{ F_2} \left( y+ix \right) + {\it C} ,$$

where $F_1,F_2$ are arbitrary functions and $C$ is a constant.

Comment: Let's see: $\nabla f = (-F'_1+F'_2,F'_1+F'_2)$ & $\nabla g = (-F'_1-F'_2,F'_1-F'_2)$ so I'm afraid that's not going to work. No wonder: your statements are equivalent to $f+g$ & $f-g$ having zero directional derivatives in the directions $(1,1)$ & $(1,-1)$, which property the PDEs do not seem to support.

Comment: @automaton3: You are right. I got the wrong system. It is corrected. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: right. & this also brings us back to holomorphic functions, since $f(z)=F_1(z)+F_2(\bar{z})$ & $g(z)={\rm i} F_1(z)-{\rm i} F_2(\bar{z})$ with $z=x+{\rm i}y$. Hence, indeed, $f(z)-{\rm i}g(z)=2F_1(z)$ is holomorphic as robjohn wrote :).